# Google Maps v3 download/visibility on pop-up action

Tags: jquery, maps

I have written a little script according to google maps API manual and it is working fine on flat show. However if I want to put the link to open it in pop-up, it is partly loaded. Here is the link to source:

jsfiddle.net/haroutweb/WrvDm/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/davidchase03/zJHAa/ ?

You have initialize the map.

so adding `initialize();` to your click function loads the entire map

let me know.

-David